# read parameters from friendly url in Struts2

Tags: struts2, friendly-url

Using Convention Plugin, I am able to achieve friendly URL in Struts2. Now, I want to read the parameter from the URL. How to acheive this.

http://domain.com/book/struts2

http://domain.com/book/hibernate

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into using the Struts2 REST plugin or something similar.  I've been quite happy with the Struts2 REST plugin myself, but I would bet Spring and other frameworks support something similar.   Here are some URLs you might find helpful.

Documentation here:
[Struts2 Rest Plugin Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html)

Also, a good tutorial that got me started can be found here:
[Struts 2 REST Example](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/01/28/rest-web-application-with-struts21-rest-and-convention-plugins/)